# Load menu in LayoutPage from database dynamically in database in Asp.net MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to load menu dynamically in layout page in MVC.

I have created Viewcode, model for menu and menuitems. Now what I want is to load the menus dynamically. It has to retrieve data from database and load in Layout page.

**My model**

**Menu Model**

```
public Menu()
{
    MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
}

public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
```

**My model MenuItem**

```
public class MenuItem
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public int UserName { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string ActionName { get; set; }
public string ControllerName { get; set; }
public string Url { get; set; }
public Menu ParentMenu { get; set; }
}
```

**My Controller Code**

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var menu = new Menu();
        menu.Name = "Main Menu";
        var query = db.ApplicationNames.Select(e => new { 
          UID=  e.UID,
             e.ApplicationName1
        }).FirstOrDefault();
        var uid = query.UID.ToString();
        var name = query.ApplicationName1;

   var items = new List<MenuItem>() { new MenuItem { Name = "FirstMenu", ControllerName = uid, ActionName = name }};
        menu.MenuItems = items;
        return PartialView("_MenuLayout",menu);
    }
```

**My partial view  _MenuLayout**

```
 @model List<DynamicMenuLoading.Models.Menu>
        <ul>
             <li>
                <a href="#">
                   <span>@Model.Name</span>
                  </a>
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.MenuItems)
                    {
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action(@item.ActionName , @item.ControllerName )"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>@item.Name</a></li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

**My Layout Page**

```
         <nav id="mainNavigation">
           @Html.Partial("_MenuLayout")
         </nav>
```

**My table name ApplicationName**

> UID ApplicationName
>
> 1      EMPLOYEE
>
> 2      CUSTOMER
>
> 3      CITY
>
> 4      STATE
>
> 5      COUNTRY

While I am trying to run my project I am getting this error:

> e:\Task
>   Tried\DynamicMenuLoading\DynamicMenuLoading\Views\Shared_MenuLayout.cshtml(8):
>   error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Can anyone tell me what mistake I did? Can anyone understand my issue and give solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptual problem: 
You need to create a separate controller action to retrieve the menu data and display the menu view.

```
public ActionResult MenuLayout()
{
    var menu = new Menu();

    // TODO: Fill menu with data here

    return PartialView("_MenuLayout", menu);
}
```

Call that Action from the layout page:

```
<nav id="mainNavigation">
    @Html.Action("MenuLayout", "Home")
</nav>
```

Also, in your partial view, use a model of class Menu, not a list of objects of that class:

```
@model DynamicMenuLoading.Models.Menu
```

Comment: nineberry i did all this separate controller only

Comment: can you explain your answer in detail